# How can i show a timestamp with yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm, and add 1 hour from the time when button was pressed? Objective-C, Xcode, iPhone

Tags: ios, timestamp

I have this code, but it only shows hh:mm. 
I want to show yyyy, mm and dd to. And I want to add 1 hour to the time because it will show when a certain thing will be active.

Can someone tell me how this is done? :)

```
-(IBAction)timeStampPressed:(id)sender{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];


    NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"time: %@",currentTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can achieve it via NSCalendar:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %02d %02d:%02d", [dateComponents year], [dateComponents day], [dateComponents hour] + 1, [dateComponents minute]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code

```
-(IBAction)timeStampPressed:(id)sender{

     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormatter setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a";

     NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];
     NSLog(@"time: %@",currentTime);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of setting the timeStyle and then overwriting it with a custom format?